# BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I'm having a problem for a few days now and I can't find the solution. I've been looking on the internet for hours but I can't find any answer that works for me.
I'm making an app where I have to send pictures to a webservice. I'm using Fishbun to access to the phone gallery and pick some pictures. When the pictures are picked, I use `Bitmapfactory.decodeFile()` with the returned path from Fishbun to display the pictures on the screen. It works good. The path at this moment is:

> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160321_044346.jpg

Then, I save the path in a ArrayList which will be send to the webservice.
When I use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` on the path from the ArrayList, it returns null. The path is exactly the same as the first time, but it seems like I can't decode it twice.
If I restart the app and take back the same picture as the first time in fishbun, the `decodeFile()` also returns null. Here is the code ....
Fishbun activity result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent imageData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageData);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case Define.ALBUM_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                path = imageData.getStringArrayListExtra(Define.INTENT_PATH);
                int i = 0;
                int error=0;
                while(i<path.size()){
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.get(i));
                    if(bmp.getWidth()<bmp.getHeight()) // bmp is not null the first time, null the second time
                    {
                        error++;
                        path.remove(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(error>=1){
                    Toast.makeText(newStep7.this,R.string.rerrors, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(path.size()>0) {
                    mainAdapter.changePath(path); //display the picture on the screen without changing the path, the method name is kinda wrong
                }
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

This is the `decodeFile()` before sending my request:

```
    String imgPath = rep.getImgList().get(0);
    File file = new File(imgPath);
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    Log.d("startedfromthebottom", file.getAbsolutePath()); //show the same path as in the activityresult above
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()); //bitmap is always null
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,os);
```

Could you help me find why my bitmap is null when I decode the same file twice ?

**EDIT**:
I found the image file in my Android Device Monitor. The image size is 0 and can't be used anymore after the Outputstream

**UPDATE**: Little code change after applying bwt answer:

```
    String imgPath = rep.getImgList().get(0);
    File file = new File(imgPath);
    AtomicFile atomicFile =
            new AtomicFile(file);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = atomicFile.startWrite();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("showmethebitmap", bitmap.toString()); //Error: bitmap is null !
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,0,oos);
        oos.writeObject(bitmap);
        oos.flush();
        atomicFile.finishWrite(fos);
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        atomicFile.failWrite(fos);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) oos.close();
    }
```

Comment: What is your second code block supposed to do, exactly? That is, why are you decoding a file, and then immediately trying to compress the decoded `Bitmap` back to the same file?

Comment: what does `path.get(i)` return? is it a file with real jpeg image?

Comment: @MikeM. It's supposed to compress the file in order to send it to the webservice. I don't know if I'm doing it right since I'm stuck with the null bitmap.

Comment: @pskink path is an ArrayList of String containing the paths of the selected images in the gallery

Comment: what is it like? try to `Log.d` the value of `path.get(i)`

Comment: Ah, I see. You're "compressing" it at 100% quality (no compression), so I was a little confused.

Comment: @pskink: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160321_055934.jpg

Comment: try `adb shell ls -l  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160321_055934.jpg`

Comment: @pskink /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160321_055934.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: so you have the answer

Comment: this means the picture isn't saved in the emulated device ? but why ?

Comment: try: `adb shell ls -l /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/`

Comment: @pskink still no such file or directory :( I tried to get even higher and I only have a different response by putting this: `adb shell ls -l /storage/emulated/` and the response `lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-03-21 04:08 legacy -> /mnt/shell/emulated/0`

Comment: I edited my question: The image size is 0 when I try to open it, that's why I can't decode it. But why is this 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the image first, **then** open the output stream, as this erases the existing content.

```
  Log.d("startedfromthebottom", file.getAbsolutePath()); //show the same path as in the activityresult above
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()); //bitmap is always null
  OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,os);
```

This is a bit dangerous because if something goes wrong the image is lost. It could be a good idea to use an [AtomicFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/AtomicFile.html).

Edit (based on your updated code) :

```
    String imgPath = rep.getImgList().get(0);
    File file = new File(imgPath);
    AtomicFile atomicFile =  new AtomicFile(file);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        // read the current image
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        // open the stream (backup the current content)
        // from now on (and until finishWrite/failWrite) we cannot read the file directly
        fos = atomicFile.startWrite();
        Log.d("showmethebitmap", bitmap.toString()); //Error: bitmap is null !
        OutputStream oos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,0,oos);
        // flush but do not close the stream (@see AtomicFile doc)
        oos.flush();
        // close the stream, remove the backup
        atomicFile.finishWrite(fos);
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // recover the content from the backup
        atomicFile.failWrite(fos);
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but the bitmap is still null even after using AtomicFile :(

Comment: Do you decode the bitmap **before** creating the output stream ? The `AtomicFile` does not change that, it secures against problem occurring between opening and closing the stream (and leaving a partially written content)

Comment: Yes I did, I just updates my question so you can see the changes

Comment: 1) You need to put the line with `decodeFile` before `startWrite` (i.e. switch the 2 lines). 2) I dont understand why you are using an additional  `ObjectOutputStream` and why you are saving the bitmap twice (one time with compress, the other with writeObject) ?

Comment: I think I'm a little confused. It's the first time I use ObjectOutputStream and Bitmap.decodeFile ... however, even after switching the lines, my bitmap is still null after the decodeFile part

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has been answered ,however if someone still getting null make sure that the application has permission to read user's files